If $f$ is continuous, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x^n)dx=f(0)$
Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Define $g_{n}(x)=f(x^{n})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I want to prove that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}g_{n}(x)dx=f(0)$$
My attempt:
Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $f$ is bounded by some $M> 0$ and for every $\epsilon> 0$ there exists $\delta> 0$, such that for every $|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. For this  $\delta$ we can find $N_{\delta}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x^{n}|<\delta$ for every $n>N_{\delta}$ and we can find $\delta_{1}>0$ with $0<1-\delta_{1}<\delta$. Therefore $|f(x^{n})-f(0)|<\epsilon$, and:
$$\int_{0}^{1}g_{n}(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x^{n})dx=\int_{0}^{1-\delta_{1}}f(x^{n})dx+\int_{1-\delta_{1}}^{1}f(x^{n})dx$$
For the first integral, we have:
\begin{align} \left|\int_{0}^{1-\delta_{1}}f(x^{n})dx-f(0)\right|&\leq \left|\int_{0}^{1-\delta_{1}}f(x^{n})dx-f(0)(1-\delta_{1})\right|\\
&\leq \left|\int_{0}^{1-\delta_{1}}[f(x^{n})-f(0)]dx\right|\\
&\leq (1-\delta_{1})\epsilon <\epsilon
\end{align}
I am not sure how to handle the second integral, but I have tried using the substitution  $u=x^{n}$, and then:
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{1-\delta_{1}}^{1}f(x^{n})dx\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{n}\int_{(1-\delta_{1})^{n}}^{1}f(u)u^{\frac{1}{n}-1}du\right|\\
&\leq \left|\frac{M}{n}\int_{(1-\delta_{1})^{n}}^{1}u^{\frac{1}{n}-1}du\right|=M\delta_{1}
\end{align}
¿ How can I bound this last integral with $\epsilon$ ?
¿ Should I modify or place restrictions on $\delta$ or $\delta_{1}$ ?

Basically, the problem is the same; in the end, there is a second integral that is bounded by $\delta$, but I am looking for a bound in terms of epsilon.

This is not a proof-verification site if that's what your question is meant to be

When we have :
$$\int_{0}^{1}g_{n}(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x^{n})dx=\int_{0}^{\delta}f(x^{n})dx+\int_{\delta}^{1}f(x^{n})dx$$
where $0 \lt \delta \lt 1$ , we can easily make the terms $0+\int_{\delta}^{1}f(x^{n})dx$ , then we can arbitrarily increase $\delta$ till $1$.
In that Case , we can take the limit $\delta \to 1$ to get :
$$\int_{\delta}^{1}f(x^{n})dx=\int_{1}^{1}f(x^{n})dx=F(1)-F(1)=0$$

The $\delta$ was found in terms of an arbitrary $\epsilon$. How is it possible that we can arbitrarily increase $\delta$ to 1 if we are bound by the conditions of $\epsilon$?

My $\delta$ was not your $\delta$ , @JuanFerRp , my way was not involving $\epsilon$ here. All $x$ values less than $1$ have $x^n \equiv 0$ in the limit. That will leave only $x=1$ , nothing more.
